Retriggering a timer on RP2 micropython?
Context: Micropython RP2 port on Pico.
I want to code a software retriggerable monostable, ie timer A has an async 1 sec delay that, while running, can be retriggered by event B to restart timing from 1 sec.
If event B does not occur then timer A will run to completion.
This should behave like a watchdog timer but is part of normal code (it should not reset the micro).
Any suggestions how this is usually done using asyncio or other timer functions?
In the docs, RP2 time and uasyncio modules don't seem to offer sleep() or delay() with this 'restart' feature. de_init() doesn't do what I want either.
I tried clearing timer-task A from the task queue and reloading it again, which works, but I found that was so slow that it missed some B events.
The simple and old-school solution is to have a global counter variable being counted down by a periodic task A, and event B reloads the counter. A raises an event if it counts down to zero. However, this seems the wrong use of asyncio.
Is there a ready-made asyncio timer with a restart feature? Thanks.
